# Kafka example, log4j WARN and MANIFEST.MF

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I am new in kafka, I try to do this example https://github.com/smallnest/kafka-example-in-scala
I have windows 10 so I also try to find some information on this website http://blog.anilot.tk/2014/08/06/Set-Up-Kafka-On-Windows/

My problem starts when I try to run this producer.

```
java -cp kafka_example-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.colobu.kafka.ScalaProducerExample 10000 test_topic localhost:9092
```

At the beggining I had problem with log4j:

```
log4j:WARN no appenders could be found for logger kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties
log4j:Warn Please initialize the log4j system properly
sent per second: 129870
```

I read somewhere that I can add this in the command line:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/your/log4j.properties
```

It's work, but I get something like this:

```
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,567] INFO Verifying properties (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,583] INFO Property metadata.broker.list is overridden to localhost:9092 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,583] INFO Property producer.type is overridden to async (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,598] INFO Property serializer.class is overridden to kafka.serializer.StringEncoder (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,645] WARN Can't read Kafka version from MANIFEST.MF. Possible cause: java.lang.NullPointerException (kafka.common.AppInfo$)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,714] INFO Shutting down producer (kafka.producer.Producer)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,730] INFO Begin shutting down ProducerSendThread (kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,730] INFO Fetching metadata from broker id:0,host:localhost,port:9092 with correlation id 0 for 1 topic(s) Set(test_topic) (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,783] INFO Connected to localhost:9092 for producing (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,799] INFO Disconnecting from localhost:9092 (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,830] INFO Connected to MYNAMEPC:9092 for producing (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,984] INFO Shutdown ProducerSendThread complete (kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,999] INFO Closing all sync producers (kafka.producer.ProducerPool)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,999] INFO Disconnecting from MYNAMEPC:9092 (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2016-07-17 12:39:17,999] INFO Producer shutdown completed in 285 ms (kafka.producer.Producer)
```

I try to find solution but my effort was unsuccessful.
I will be grateful for help.

Comment: If you're using log4j 1.2, trying removing `file:///` and give it the path directly.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not work, when I remove  file:/// then it shows log4j WARN again

Comment: I don't know exactly what was the problem, but when I wrote my own producer then works.